# Can a non-captured variable be shadowed by a lambda parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda, shadow, clang++

I have a code that looks like this - it's heavily simplified but this snippet compiles and exhibits the same behaviour:

```
template <typename TFunc>
float FloatSelect( const float in_value, TFunc&& Predicate) {
  return std::forward<TFunc>(Predicate)(in_value) ? in_value : 0.0f;
};

void DisplayFloatSelect() {
  const float value = FloatSelect(
    -1.0f,
    [] (const float value) { return value > 0.0f; }
  );

  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

With -Wshadow enabled the compiler emits the following warning (as seen [here](http://goo.gl/6dRVnE)):

```
12 : warning: declaration shadows a local variable [-Wshadow]

[] (const float value) { return value > 0.0f; }

^

10 : note: previous declaration is here

const float value = FloatSelect(

^
```

Which is not really helpful - I understand what shadowing a variable is about but as the lambda does not capture anything, it should be fine here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Its helpful because maybe you meant to capture it and aren't (and you're not getting the [relevant error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2b67408a861b26d) due to shadowing).

Comment: Nothing, the warning makes no sense.

Comment: You've used the same variable name in two nested contexts, the compiler doesn't know if that was intentional, so it gives a warning. That's the point of that warning. The original `value` is in scope in the body of the lambda, it's just ill-formed to refer to it without capturing it.

Comment: Comments are for requesting clarification, guys, not giving answers. Join me down there ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: The question in the title of your post is missing from the post. The question in the post is less emphatic.

Comment: Looking at this piece of code, I smell fish. Why should anyone have two variables with the same name in overlapped scopes? Isn't this code a result of some hasty reorganization? Does its author realize what it does? Or probably it's a result of a failed attempt to convey some idea? If the compiler gives a warning, it deserves credit for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, a non-captured variable can be shadowed by a lambda parameter.

In the particular case of the lambda in the OP, you might argue that the inner declaration of `value` does not shadow the scope of the outer declaration because the lambda has no captures. Nonetheless, the outer `value` can be seen inside the body of the lambda, because the body of the lambda is still inside the scope of the enclosing block:

> (C++14 §5.1.2/p.7): The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body (8.4) of the function call operator, but ***for purposes of name lookup*** (3.4), determining the type and value of this (9.3.2) and transforming idexpressions referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) (9.3.1), ***the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression***.

The odr-use of a non-captured variable from the outer scope is an error, but it is possible for a lambda without captures to make use of a name defined in an outer scope if it is not an odr-use (and in such a case, the variable is *not* captured.) In particular, it is possible to use `const` variables from an outer scope:

```
const int i = 20;
int f = ([](){return i + 3;})();
```

So even though the lambda has no captures, an explicit argument named `i` would certainly shadow the outer `i`. (See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/006f5f20cca841d5; you might want to try enabling -Wshadow.)

Since `-Wshadow` is precisely intended to reveal this sort of ambiguous name usage, it doesn't seem too surprising that it triggers a warning in the case in the OP.

`-Wshadow` is not enabled by either `-Wall` nor by `-Wextra` precisely because it is often going to warn you about something you don't really care about.

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely the answer I was looking for - this code is not nice indeed but I was curious to know about the reason for the warning.
The exemple with the const variable speaks for itself.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing that compilers are not perfect and sometimes emit silly warnings for relatively new language features in circumstances where they don't make much sense.

On the other hand, warnings are often all about ensuring that you *really* meant to write the code you wrote, instead of some other code. Perhaps you meant to capture the outer `value` but — for whatever reason: perhaps you weren't paying attention — failed to capture it and redeclared it instead.

In this code that does seem like a bit of a stretch, but the point is that warnings don't *always* tell you about the code you wrote: they sometimes tell you about the code the compiler thinks you possibly *meant* to write.

And then it's pretty trivial to use a different name for this parameter to say "hey, yeah, I know".

That would also make for much clearer code with a well-documented intent.

Comment: Where the annoying part 'they sometimes tell you about the code the compiler thinks you possibly meant to write' is no good (trying to write warning free code)

Comment: @DieterLücking: It's extremely rare that that is not trivial to "fix". And, usually, this happens when your code was less than optimally clear anyway. I addressed this in my answer.